# Prove that {$v,T(v)$} are L.I.Describe the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

The dimension of $V$ is $2$.So I have to prove that $v,T(v)$ are Linearly Independent where $T$ is not a scalar operator.

Since $T$ is not a scalar operator so there exists a vector $v \in V$ such that $T(v) \ne \lambda v$.

Proving Linear Independence

$c_1(v)+c_2T(v)=0$.

We see that $v=ae_1+be_2$ and $T(v)=b_1e_1+b_2e_2$ where {$e_1,e_2$} are standard basis of $V$.

Now $(c_1a_1+c_2b_1)e_1+(c_1a_2+c_2b_2)e_2=0$.

Then $a_1=(-\frac{c_2}{c_1}b_1)$ which is possible only when $c_2=0$ otherwise $b_1$ and $b_2$ will both become a scalar multiple of $a_1,a_2$ contrary to our assumption. From here we can conclude that $T(v),v$ are linearly independent.

Now since they are independent so they form the basis of $V$ and $T(v)= 0.v+1.T(v)$
$T(T(v))=av+bT(v)$.

This has been my attempt .can someone point out my mistake instead of suggesting another method and how I can rectify it.Also I dont have any idea how to create a matrix in stack exchange .Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Even if $\;T\;$ is not  scalar operator it could be that $\;Tv=0\;$ , so that $\;\{v,\,Tv=0\}\;$ would automatically be linearly dependent. Perhaps you meant to show there exists an $\;v\;$  such that $\;Tv\neq0\;$ ?

Comment: How do I conclude that $T(v) \ne 0$ .Should I be using that $T(v) \ne \lambda v$ where $\lambda \in R$ so it can be $0$ also?

Comment: @DonAntonio $v$ has the property that $Tv \neq \lambda v$ for all the scalars $\lambda$, so, $Tv \neq 0v = 0$.

Comment: Is the rest of the proof ok?

Comment: @azif00 That is not specifically stated so by the OP, and this is the reason I asked him. The very question is very confusing...

Comment: The proper question should be, imo.: prove that if $\;T\;$ is *not* a scalar operator, then there always exist $\;v\in V\;$ s.t. $\;\{v,\,Tv\}\;$ are linearly  independent. This calim is, apparently, what the OP tries to prove

Comment: @smita You write "Then $a_1=(-\frac{c_2}{c_1}b_1)$ which is possible only when $c_2=0$ otherwise $b_1$ and $b_2$ will both become a scalar multiple of $a_1,a_2$ contrary to our assumption" . What assumption...where? Besides this, that $\;T\;$ isn't a scalar operator *doesn't mean* that exists $\;v\in V\;$ s.t. $\;Tv\neq\lambda v\;$ (what is $\;\lambda\;$ here, for example? Of course, a scalar...but how you take it?), but rather that there is not scalar $\;\lambda\;$ s.t. $\;Tv=\lambda v\;$ for all $\;v\;$ ...!

Answer (score 1):

Since $T$ is not a scalar operator so there exists a vector $v∈V$ such that $T(v)≠λv.$

let $v$ and $T(v)$ be linearly dependent then there exists $c_1,c_2$ such that

$c_1v+c_2T(v)=0$ $\Rightarrow$ $c_2T(v)=c_1v$

$c_2T(v)=-c_1v$ $\Rightarrow$ $T(v)=\frac{-c_1}{c_2}v=\lambda v$ for $\lambda=\frac{-c_1}{c_2}$

that is a contradiction so $v$ and $T(v)$ must be linearly independent

$dimV=|\{v,T(v)\}|=2$ $\Rightarrow$ $\{v,T(v)\}$ is a basis